# Enviar correo eletrónico en Swift

Tags: swift, email, app

Estoy haciendo una app tipo `todoList` pero con notas de audio con extensión `mp4` y `m4a`, entonces quisiera saber si ¿hay alguna forma de mandar ese archivo de audio por medio de un correo electrónico desde la app?

y si la hay, ¿Como lo puedo realizar?

Answer (score 1):

Sí, hay forma de adjuntar un audio. Podes fijarte acá https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397500/how-to-attach-recorded-audio-into-email-in-swift#31439258 donde te muestra un código para enviar un audio como adjunto. Lo único que deberias cambiar es el mimeType a "audio/x-m4a" o "audio/mp4".